# Translation of protest sign?

Tags: переклад

I am a student researching Russification, and I came across these protest signs over the Russification of Ukrainian culture. I tried to plug them into various translation services, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help! [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Left:` Let's speak Ukrainian, so that Russia does not come to "defend" the Russian-speakers.

`Right:` Russian language is a Russian weapon! Do not speak the imperial language!